# Почему через PDO выводится только одна зав

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

У меня есть функция вывода записей

```
     public function getAllContracts(){
         $sql = "SELECT 
          stage.*,
          document.*,
          stage.contracrt,
          stage.status,
          contract.numberContract,
          department.departmentName
        FROM document
          INNER JOIN stage
            ON document.stage = stage.id_stage
          INNER JOIN contract
            ON stage.contracrt = contract.idContract
          INNER JOIN department
            ON contract.department = department.idDepartment
        WHERE stage.status = 'Ожиданиие скачивания'";
         $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute();
         while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $result[$row['idContract']] = $row;
        }
  
        if(isset($result)){
            return $result; 
        }
}
```

Проверив запрос в phpMyAdmin, выводится две строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В php выводится одна строка :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже если строк в базе данных будет очень много, то всегда будет выводится одна строка :(

Comment: этот код перебирает все строки. другое дело что результат индексируется по idContract и если он в обеих строках совпадает, то разумеется в массиве останется только одна

Comment: @Ипатьев в данном случае скорее отсутствует, а не совпадает.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто :(

```
$result= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: исходные способ работал бы, если бы поле `idContract` присутствовало в выборке.